# SFTP using cURL

Tags: command-line, curl, sftp

I am trying to ftp a file via sftp protocol to a client:

```
curl -u username --key C:\cygwin\home\XJ0002T\.ssh\id_rsa --pubkey c:\cygwin\home\XJ0002T\.ssh\id_rsa.pub -
T c:\temp2\test4.txt sftp://server/SFTP/ --insecure
```

Enter host password for user `XJ0002T`:

Curl keeps asking me for a password.  I have tried key pairs using OpenSSH and puttyGen, neither worked.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: turn on --verbose, find appropriate output where your connection is being refused, and either fix or append an edited version of that output to you message. Good Luck.

Comment: Belongs to http://superuser.com/

Comment: try: `curl -v -u XJ0002T:password4xjoo2t ...`

Answer (score 8):

## Explicitly provide blank password

curl asks you for a password because you use `-u` and provide a username but no password.

Provide a blank password instead with `-u username:` (notice the trailing colon) and it will stop asking.