# Jenkins copy files between 2 Server

Tags: linux, jenkins

Is it possible to copy an .war file from one server to another server. I know there is the command `scp` but it doesn't support password & username. So there is like the command `sshpass` but I heard about some security problems with this command.

My question now: is there a way to pass an password trough the **scp** command without something like **sshpass**?

Comment: How about key-based authorization instead of password for ssh?

Comment: @arasio yeah heard about that. But I'm looking for a workaround for this.

Comment: you can add your key in .ssh/authorized_keys so that only that particular server will access it without key/password

Comment: I found a way: try using curl it's much easier!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682637/sftp-using-curl